# Linq optional parameters query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am making a search form that queries my database to show results based on what has been filled out on the form. The only required field is the date which I have working. all the other fields are optional, if an optional field is not filled in it should not be a part of the query. This is the code I have written:

```
            var queryable = context.TransactionJournal.Where(s => s.TransactionDateTime <= transactionDate)
                .Where(s => Region == null || Region == s.AcquirerID)
                .Where(s => MCC == null || MCC == s.MerchantCategoryCode)
                .Where(s => MerchantID == null || MerchantID.Contains(s.MerchantID))
                .Where(s => TxnCurrency == null || TxnCurrency.Contains(s.Currency))
                .Where(s => TerminalID == null || TerminalID.Contains(s.TerminalID))
                .Where(s => TxnAmount.ToString() == null || TxnAmount==(s.TransactionAmount))
                .Where(s => BIN == null || BIN.Contains(s.Bin))
                .Where(s => MsgType == null || MsgType.Contains(s.MessageType))
                .Where(s => MaskedPan == null || MaskedPan.Contains(s.PANM))
                .Where(s => ProcessingCode == null || ProcessingCode.Contains(s.ProcessingCode))
                .Where(s => ClearPan == null || ClearPan.Contains(s.PAN))
                .Where(s => ResponseCode == null || ResponseCode.Contains(s.ResponseCode))
                .Where(s => AuthorizationCode == null || AuthorizationCode.Contains(s.AuthorizationCode))
                .Where(s => EntryMode == null || EntryMode.Contains(s.PosEntryMode))
                .AsQueryable();
```

Unfortunately it does not work correctly. Can someone tell me what I am missing or if there is a better way to write this?

Comment: .Where((s => Region == null || Region == s.AcquirerID) && (MCC == null || MCC == s.MerchantCategoryCode) && ....)

Comment: This looks OK to me. Although you could not chain `.Where` statements and use `&&` in their place it would be functionally equivalent to what you have now. Most importantly: "`it does not work correctly`" is not a problem statement. Please include input and expected output.

Comment: @Igor apologies the query does not show any results at all on output

Comment: @Adil15 - I understand but you need to provide input and expected output. The most likely reason you are not getting output is that one of those conditions in a `Where` clause is evaluating to `false` and you are just not catching it (you are human after all and can make mistakes or fail to notice something). But no one can help you spot that error if you do not have sample data with sample input.

Comment: @Adil15 try 'debug' it by removing more of the statements. You will find that one of the statements return false

Comment: Thank you both! Solved the problem by doing what you guys told me to do. One of my where clauses was indeed throwing a false. I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Took advice from the comments and went through each line and found which line was evaluating false. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do there is check first if you should apply the condition and then filter the list.

An example using the code you provided.

```
             var queryable = context.TransactionJournal.Where(s => s.TransactionDateTime <= transactionDate);

             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(your_objet.Region) 
             {
                var queryable = queryable.Where(x=>x.Region == your_objet.Region).AsQueryable();
             }

             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(your_objet.MCC) 
             {
                var queryable = queryable.Where(x=>x.MCC == your_objet.MCC).AsQueryable();
             }
```

The first line is the entire list, then you check all parameters that you have in the form and evaluate it, if has value the apply the filter to list.

And the end you'll get your list filtered.